# How does one add something as a dot after a counter inside a content property in TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-counter

I have this numbered list (I have omitted the counter-reset and counter-increment for legibility):

```
<ol class="...">
    <li class="... before:content-[counter(name)]">I like cheese</li>
</ol>
```

which results in

`1I like cheese`

I would like to add a period and a space after the counter, so it becomes:

`1. I like cheese`

but the framework won't let me parse something that normally would work in vanilla CSS:

```
content: counter(name) '. ';
```

How do I work around this without having to add a hard-coded class myself? Or perhaps, is there a proper way of handling this, by making a particular plugin that would accept a similar value?

Edit: I now realize there indeed is something as `list-decimal` which exactly does this too, but I am specifically curious about a working alternative if one would still use a CSS-counter in a `before`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ol class="list-decimal list-inside">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

i think this is what you are trying to do.

https://flowbite.com/docs/typography/lists/

Comment: Admitted: this does indeed exactly create a number (in a native way) and adds a period. I'm afraid however that I failed to formulate the question specifically enough to describe what I am actually curious about, which is: what would I do if I _do_ want to use a counter, where I could hypothetically replace the dot with anything, such as a colon or a hyphen?

Answer (score 0):

try this syntax class="[content:counters(section'.')]". without a comma after 'section'. But it will break lists counting inside, and will start from 1, 2, 3...